# How to get object's initial position in ARKit

Tags: arkit

Apologies for the simple question. I'm looking at Apple's Augmented Reality App starter code and noticed that the plane starts at position (0, -0.1, -0.8). I want to get (and change) this position programmatically. I have tried:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let childNodes = scene.rootNode.childNodes
    let rootNode = scene.rootNode
    let rootNodePresentation = rootNode.presentation
    let ship = childNodes[0]
    let shipPresentation = ship.presentation

    print(rootNode.position) // (0,0,0)
    print(rootNode.worldPosition) // (0,0,0)
    print(rootNode.simdWorldPosition) // (0,0,0)
    print(rootNode.worldTransform) // Identity matrix

    print(rootNodePresentation.position) // (0,0,0)
    print(rootNodePresentation.worldPosition) // (0,0,0)
    print(rootNodePresentation.simdWorldPosition) // (0,0,0)
    print(rootNodePresentation.worldTransform) // Identity matrix

    print(ship.position) // (0,0,0)
    print(ship.worldPosition) // (0,0,0)
    print(ship.simdWorldPosition) // (0,0,0)
    print(ship.worldTransform) // Identity matrix

    print(shipPresentation.position)  // (0,0,0)
    print(shipPresentation.worldPosition) // (0,0,0)
    print(shipPresentation.simdWorldPosition) // (0,0,0)
    print(shipPresentation.worldTransform) // Identity matrix
}
```

Where can I get the value (0,-0.1,-0.8) from the ship node?

Comment: Can you point to where you saw this vector (0, -0.1, -0.8), or explain in more detail why you are expecting it here? Additional code may help